# Would the process of determining whether a string has been modified cause performance hits? If so, could we optimize this further?

Tags: c#, optimization

I am in need of a way to detect whether a `string` changes within my code, however, I am at the same time cautious about my performance:

In reference to this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596006/how-do-i-determine-if-the-value-of-a-string-variable-changed-in-c).

Specifically, this code snippet:

```
// holds a copy of the previous value for comparison purposes
private string oldString = string.Empty; 

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the new string value
    string newString = //some varying value I get from other parts of my program

    // Compare the old string to the new one
    if (oldString != newString)
    {
        // The string values are different, so update the ListBox
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add(x + /*other things*/);   
    }

    // Save the new value back into the temporary variable
    oldString = newString;
}
```

I am currently working on a Grasshopper 3D component. Each component is itself a class library, and the `main` method is a method called `SolveInstance()`. The condition in which it runs I'm not actually too sure, but what I do know is that in the minimum, it runs a number of times a section, so your graphical UI pretty much is real-time, or so imperceptible to the human eye.

For my particular example, this is what my particular case would look like (it's untested psuedo-code).

```
// instance vars
private string _oldOutputString = string.Empty; 
private string _newOutputString = string.Empty;


// Begin SolveInstance() method
// This constructor call saves a string to _newOutputString based on two lists
_valueList = new ValueList(firstList, secondList);

// Compare the old string to the new one
if (_oldOutputString != _newOutputString)
{
    // Save the new value back into the temporary variable
    _oldOutputString = _newOutputString;

    // Call eventargs method
    Menu_MyCustomItemClicked(_sender, _e);
}

DA.SetData(0, _oldOutputStr);
```

My question is: Would doing this, where that particular piece of code gets called many times a second, take a hit in performance?

Comment: `Would doing this, where that particular piece of code gets called many times a second, take a hit in performance?` - You could benchmark   to find out

Comment: Try it and find out.  There's no way for us to know what it's doing, or how long it takes to do that.  Since you already have the code, just try it and see if it takes too long to be effective.

Comment: Comparing strings in .NET is usually very fast, since strings are inlined and share memory. So you're actually only string references, not their contents.

Comment: BTW, anything that has to do with winforms will be slow. If your code is performance-sensitive, remove the winforms stuff and perform your operations in a background thread that has nothing to do with UI.

Comment: First time I am actually caring about real-world performance.. I apologize for the uninformed question. I will run some tests.

Comment: Where is `_newOutputString` assigned? Is it *always* reassigned (from a control, I presume) or only if a change occurs?

Comment: It's assigned in a method above, inside the `Menu_MyCustomItemClicked( sender, e)`, like this: `_newOutputStr = _valueList.SecondList[index];`

Comment: As an aside, `ListBox` in winforms doesn't support [UI Virtualization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA) and therefore is slow as hell. If you really care about performance, forget winforms. If you really care about winforms, forget performance.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage If the text was changed to something other than the original and then changed right back to the original manually (before this code was run twice), would you consider it a change?

Comment: Since it's controlled by a GUI, I don't think there would be any situations like that. Any time there is a change, it would propagate almost instantaneously. At least that's what I think.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Then I think you could compare for reference equality instead of using `==` and have pretty much the result you want.

Comment: Ah good point. A fundamental C# and Java mistake I made.

Comment: @knittl that's not true at all; it often happens that two matching strings are the same reference, and we sometimes take pains to make it happen more often than one might expect otherwise, but it certainly isn't always the case.

Comment: @knittl Literal strings are interned.  Strings that were generated at runtime, rather than being compile time literals, are not interned unless explicitly interned by the programmer using `string.Intern`.  It seems that in this case the strings are generated at runtime, not compile time, so it's unlikely that they'll be interned.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis The `==` operator will first check if the references are equal, and only compare the values of the strings if the references are unequal.  Since you cannot be sure that all reference unequal strings are actually different, this is the desired behavior.  He most certainly should not be changing this to use `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @Servy I think you're right. I didn't look up that part of the operator's definition before replying, my bad!

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Technically it's not the operator's definition, it's simply an implementation detail of the string's implementation of its overload.  While, by definition, it does a value comparison, as an optimization it checks the references as an "early out" for the realistic case that the references are equal.  Technically this is an implementation detail, not a part of the specs.

Comment: @Servy Yep, that's what I meant when I said definition. I usually keep a copy of the BCL sources to consult when answering these kinds of questions, but I happened not to have them handy right now. Of course, it makes sense that they would have already optimized something so obvious.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the very informative discussion. I made some changes, and now I am using `List<string>`s instead of strings. I am comparing `List<string>` using `cachedStringList.SequenceEqual(newStringList)`. Would this have any effect on performance at all? I am also storing the old string lists into a private variable.

Comment: Are you sure you're optimizing the right thing? First, if it's not a bottleneck (that is, you haven't profiled the code and identified that string comparison as a problem area), then you're wasting your time. Second, if your `DA.SetData()` method does anything significant, the time it takes will almost certainly dwarf the cost of a string comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would doing this, where that particular piece of code gets called many times a second, take a hit in performance?

Yes.

That's not the important thing though, the important thing is will it cause a **significant** hit.

Which is a matter of how long it takes, vs. what's significant to you.

The only way to know is to measure.

However, it's worth considering what makes some string comparisons slower than others.

The fastest string comparison is where two strings are in fact the exact same object. In particular;

```
string a = "ABC";
string b = a;
bool c = a == b; // Very fast.
```

The next fastest is when one, but not both are null (both being null is an example of the above case, anyway).

The next fastest is when they have different lengths, for those types of comparisons where they can't be equivalent if they have the different lengths. This doesn't apply to case-sensitive comparisons because if you capitalise "weißbier" to "WEISSBEIR" the lengths are different, but does to exact-match comparisons.

The next fastest is when they differ early on.

The slowest is when two strings are different objects, but are in fact equal.

The average cost of string equality tests are proportional to the length of the strings.

We can reduce the speed of the slowest by interning strings (whether in the default intern pool, or a custom cache of strings) and if we know all strings have gone through the same process we can make all equality comparisons as fast as the fastest case (because we've made sure that either two strings will be the same string, or they'll not be equivalent). However doing so in itself takes time, so it's not always worth it.

In all, if you are only changing the string on a real change, then it in practice will be much faster than if you are building up the string repeatedly, potentially to end up with the same string as you had to begin with.

Comment: Hey Jon. Thanks for the in-depth answer. From what I get, I should use `bool c = a == b` as my condition checker is that right?

Comment: Well, the same applies in to `!=`. `oldString != newString` will be just as fast if they're the same actual string, but potentially slow otherwise. Knowing which applies to your case would require analysis of how `newString` comes to have its value set.

Answer (score 1):

That string comparison should take on the order of a microsecond or less.

You're only doing it once per button click.

How fast can you click a button - ten times per second?

That means, worst case, that comparison can cost you on the order of ten microseconds per second, or 0.001 percent of time.

Don't worry about anything taking less than 1 percent of time, or even 10%, because if you could fix it, it would save you no more than that.

Comment: I made some changes, and now I am using `List<string>`s instead of `string`s. I am comparing `List<string>` using `cachedStringList.SequenceEqual(newStringList)`. Would this have any effect on performance at all? The `cachedStringList` is assigned into a `private` variable, and I also `_cachedFirstList = firstList;` at the end of the code to save the new list into the temporary `private` var.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Same idea. If you're only doing it on a button click, you can do a heck of a lot more than that before you'll ever notice any slowness. Where UI apps get slow is when they start hitting databases, file IO, massive screen repainting, or massive data structure updating with `new`s, GC, notifications etc. Banging on a few strings is probably not worth thinking about. The last time I worried about things like that, machines were about a thousand times slower.